# App crashs trying to get a view from segue (swift - iOS)

Tags: ios, swift

So, I'm building an app using OMDB API to search movies from IMDB. There two ways to search, by the movie title, that returns: Poster, Title, Type, Year, imdbID. The other way is search by imdbTitle, that returns only one movie with a lot more things like Actors, Director, etc. My search is working fine, I get a list of movies when I type on searchbar a movie title. But, when I click on a movie to show a view with the movie details, my app crash. I put some prints on code to see how far it goes, and it crashes when I try to execute my getMovieByID function.

Here's what I'm trying to do...

Get a movie by its id on OMDB API using Alamofire:

```
func getMovieByIdJSON(imdbID: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Dictionary<String, String>) -> Void) {

let url = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=\(imdbID)"

Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON {
    response in

    if let json = response.result.value {
        completionHandler((json as? Dictionary<String, String>)!)
    } 
  }

}
```

Then, I have my movie class:

```
class Movie {

var poster, title, runtime, director, actors, genre,
plot, production, year, imdbID, imdbRating : String?

init(poster: String?, title: String?, runtime: String?, director: String?, actors: String?, genre: String?, plot: String?, production: String?, year: String?, imdbID: String?, imdbRating: String?) {

    if let isPoster = poster { self.poster = isPoster }
    else { self.poster = nil }

    if let isTitle = title { self.title = isTitle }
    else { self.title = nil }

    if let isRuntime = runtime { self.runtime = isRuntime }
    else { self.runtime = nil }

    if let isDirector = director { self.director = isDirector }
    else { self.director = nil }

    if let isActors = actors { self.actors = isActors }
    else { self.actors = nil }

    if let isGenre = genre { self.genre = isGenre }
    else { self.genre = nil }

    if let isPlot = plot { self.plot = isPlot }
    else { self.plot = nil }

    if let isProduction = production { self.production = isProduction }
    else { self.production = nil }

    if let isYear = year { self.year = isYear }
    else { self.year = nil }

    if let isImdbID = imdbID { self.imdbID = isImdbID }
    else { self.imdbID = nil }

    if let isImdbRating = imdbRating { self.imdbRating = isImdbRating }
    else { self.imdbRating = nil }

  }
}
```

My MovieDAO to get a movie by ID:

```
class MovieDAO {

func getMovieByID(imdbID: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Movie) -> ()) {

    getMovieByIdJSON(imdbID: imdbID, completionHandler: {
        (dict) in

        let movie: Movie = Movie(poster: dict["Poster"]!, title: dict["Title"]!, runtime: dict["Runtime"]!, director: dict["Director"]!, actors: dict["Actors"]!, genre: dict["Genre"]!, plot: dict["Plot"]!, production: dict["Production"]!, year: dict["Year"]!, imdbID: dict["imdbID"]!, imdbRating: dict["imdbRating"]!)

        completionHandler(movie)
    })
  }

}
```

And finally, the code that maybe is causing this mess...

On my SearchTableViewController I have this segue prepare:

```
let searchSegue = "segueFromSearch"

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destination = segue.destination as? MovieViewController
    let searchIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
    let selectedImdbID = self.movies[searchIndex!].imdbID

    print("IMDB_ID: \(String(describing: selectedImdbID))")

    if segue.identifier == searchSegue {
        destination?.movieImdbID = selectedImdbID!
        print("Debug print: I get til here")
    }
}
```

And the view that shows the movie details have this MovieViewController:

```
import UIKit

class MovieViewController: UIViewController {

let DAO: MovieDAO = MovieDAO()
var movie: Movie? = nil
var movieImdbID: String?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("Movie Controller view didLoad - before get the movie function")

    DAO.getMovieByID(imdbID: self.movieImdbID!, completionHandler: {
        movieResult in

        print("Imdb self.movie: \(String(describing: self.movie))")
        self.movie = movieResult

        print("after self.movie")

    }) 
  }
}
```

I simulated an attempt to see a movie details, my console output is this:

```
2017-04-25 09:29:17.016079-0300 Favorite Movies[14492:460113] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
IMDB_ID: Optional("tt0437236")
Debug print: I get til here
Movie Controller view didLoad - before get the movie function
(lldb)
```

So, I guess the problem is with this function in my MovieViewController, since the app crash right when it try to execute it. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? What am I missing here?

PS.: Sorry about the bunch of code but I tried to explain and show all the path until the crash, because maybe the problem isn't here where I'm thinking it is.

### Update: ##

xcode show this:
[![xcode][1]][1]

### Update 2

As asked by @unkg here is the Line 13 from my getMovieByIdJSON:
[image: Line 13]

PS.: I have notice the my segue function is passing (as printed on console) "Optional("tt0944849")". Is that right? This Optional printed is passed too as part of the String?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: any crash log ?

Comment: Are you sure the `segue.destination` is your MovieViewController? I suggest putting a breakpoint in `prepare(for segue:)` and go through the variables and check if any of them is nil

Comment: @ChanJingHong it is not nil, as you can see, on my segue prepare function, it prints the movie ID on console. I mean, at this point there is a movie ID. But I don't know why when I call my function getMovieByID receiving this ID from prepare segue, the app crash.

Comment: @Sweeper I updated with a image of the error

Comment: @U23r, it seems the crash is in the method - in the DataTask according to the stack trace, the interesting part is the "line 13" part, with the getMovieIdByJSON, select that line and then show the screen shot so we can see what happens inside the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at a sample omdbapi response, I don't think you can reliably cast to `Dictionary<String, String>`.  Note `Ratings: []` is an empty `Array`.  You may need to cast to `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`.  I'd be careful about the force unwrapping too.

Be sure to unwrap `selectedImdbID` if its printing as Optional.

https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt4649466

```
{
    "Title": "Kingsman: The Golden Circle",
    "Year": "2017",
    "Rated": "N/A",
    "Released": "29 Sep 2017",
    "Runtime": "N/A",
    "Genre": "Action, Adventure, Comedy",
    "Director": "Matthew Vaughn",
    "Writer": "Jane Goldman (screenplay), Matthew Vaughn (screenplay), Mark Millar (characters), Dave Gibbons (characters)",
    "Actors": "Taron Egerton, Channing Tatum, Julianne Moore, Pedro Pascal",
    "Plot": "When their headquarters are destroyed and the world is held hostage, the Kingsman's journey leads them to the discovery of an allied spy organization in the US. These two elite secret organizations must band together to defeat a common enemy.",
    "Language": "English",
    "Country": "UK, USA",
    "Awards": "N/A",
    "Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNTBlOWZhZTctOTY0MC00Y2QyLTljMmYtZDkxZDFlMWU4Y2EyXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDg2MjUxNjM@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    "Ratings": [],
    "Metascore": "N/A",
    "imdbRating": "N/A",
    "imdbVotes": "N/A",
    "imdbID": "tt4649466",
    "Type": "movie",
    "DVD": "N/A",
    "BoxOffice": "N/A",
    "Production": "20th Century Fox",
    "Website": "http://www.foxmovies.com/movies/kingsman-the-golden-circle",
    "Response": "True"
}
```

---

As a side note, I am a big fan of [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper).  With that, you could convert your Movie class into something like this

```
class Movie: Mappable {
    var poster, title, runtime, director, actors, genre, plot, production, year, imdbID, imdbRating : String?

    required init?(map: Map) {
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        poster    <- map["Poster"]
        title     <- map["Title"]
        runtime   <- map["Runtime"]
        director  <- map["Director"]
        //...etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for @dmorrow response. Your crash is not related to segue or any iOS system calls. Your screenshot is not conclusive but JSON deserialization is what's failing. You could use ObjectMapper as a library dependency, static or via dependency manager for updating. Or you could use code-generation tools, like AhmedAli's JSONEXport https://github.com/Ahmed-Ali/JSONExport (requires you to build his solution in your XCode as a Mac OS application)

Comment: Hey, @dmorrow, thanks! I followed your suggestion and I'm trying to do this way, but I have some doubts and another error. Could you help with that? Question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623796/error-resquest-function-with-alamofire-and-alamofireobjectmapper-swift-ios